# filtering rows in a gridview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a gridview that contains user info and one of the columns is a date when the user was added to the system.

Is it possible to use the **GridView.onRowCreated** method to check if the user was added within a given time frame?  If the user was added within that timeframe, then the row is added, if not, then that row is not added.

Note that I can't modify the datasource of the gridview, so I need to do this somehow as the gridview is being created.

Comment: Use rowdatabound event to capture the user **http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx**

Comment: "Can't modify the datasource" are you sure, that does not make sense.

Comment: I see how I can use RowDataBound to change the style of a row, but I cant figure out how to actually get the gridview to display or not display the row based on a condition - thanks

Comment: Change/Increase/Decrease your DataSource before assigning it to GridView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `RowBoundData` and set teh row to hide based on your certain condition

```
Protected Sub GridView_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As GridViewRowEventArgs)
    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
        e.Row.Visible = True ' base on some condition
    End If
End Sub
```

---

Another Method is to filter your Data. pass the filter expression in the below function and it will return you the desired output. You can do this before your binding.

```
Public NotInheritable Class GetFilteredData
    Private Sub New()
    End Sub
    <System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension> _
    Public Shared Function FilterDataTable(Dt As DataTable, FilterExpression As String) As DataTable
        Using Dv As New DataView(Dt)
            Dv.RowFilter = FilterExpression
            Return Dv.ToTable()
        End Using
    End Function
End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

You can filter out your gridview datasource and bind to gridview depends upon your where condition on date column. this will be easy solution than putting condition on the gridview event.

Cheers!!